# How to make a unique column in datagridview with c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, unique

how to prevent repeating of rows in datagridview while adding rows?

I need to make a unique column like in sql.

is there any way to do this via properties window or programmaticalLy?

Comment: What data source is used for `DGV`? Is it `DataTable`, or any `IList`-based collection?

Comment: there is no data source just adding rows programmatically according to some user's inputs

Comment: Before adding row, loop all existing rows and check if duplicate data exist.

Comment: @Fabio  won't  this affect performance? what if the dgv contains 100k rows or something like that?

Comment: If your `datagridview` need to contain 100k rows, then this is a your application design problem

Comment: You can use `HashSet<UniqueColumnType>` for keeping existing unique values in the memory. And before adding row check with `HashSet.Contains` method if unique value already exists. `HashSet` is much faster then looping rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the existing unique column value before adding the new one, something like,

```
    var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                                 .Where(x => x.Cells["cell1"].Value == "newCellVal1")
                                 .ToArray();
    if (rows == null || rows.Length == 0)
    {
        //New row is unique
        //Logic to add new row
    }
    else
    {
        //Row already exists with "newCellVal1"
        //Update the existing value rows
        rows[0].Cells["cell2"].Value = "newCellVal2"; //Coulmn "cell2" with a new value "newCellVal2"
        rows[0].Cells["cell3"].Value = "newCellVal3"; //Coulmn "cell3" with a new value "newCellVal3"
    }
```

Here, `cellVal` is the unique column name in the datagrid and `newCellVal` is the value of unique column from the new row. Also you can add combination of columns to check for unique values in the `Any` method.

Hope this helps...

Comment: thank you, can you write the code to edit the row if it's existing and update it's values if you please?

Comment: @Mohamed Ahmed How about this?

Comment: thank you, working as a charm :) just need to update the entire existing row not just the unique column cell, so I need the code in the else close to update the entire row not just 1 cell  can you edit pls ^_^

Comment: @Mohamed Ahmed I have specified here to update `cell2` and `cell3` column values, in the same way just update all the available columns of your gridview row.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add it as a comment but I dont have the privilege . Just to give you a hint if you are populating your dgv using list or something similar you coud use the "distinct" function and give it a try. If you are reading some text file that you need to write some code to remove the duplicates.

Comment: there is no data source just adding rows programmatically according to some user's inputs. thank you

Answer (score 0):

to prevent user from adding new row, you can disable it from the properties window and set the allowusertoadd from true into false.

If you have a problem about the duplicate row or data, you have to check your datasources first.

And about making unique column, you can set it either from properties window and programatically.

Adding column from properties window, you can select the column properties and add or edit the column you want,

Programmatically, you can type this syntax :
datagridview1.columns.add("Column1");, etc

Answer (score 0):

This is not done (directly) in the DataGridView.

You will, most propably, have bound the DataGridView to a DataSource like DataTable via .net data binding (a BindingSource). If not, do so right now by adding a DataSet to your project and create a new DataTable in it.

This (DataTable) gives you an in memory table of data, which can be populated with data in any way you like (loading from database, inserting programmatically).

You can then add constraints to columns of this table as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/st1t2c35%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).